# insertNewChild is not a function in DHTML Tree grid Pro

Tags: dhtmlx

I want to access child data from server when we append parent. Now I am using

`mygrid.attachEvent("onOpenStart", getSubElements );`

When I am using `getSubElements`, this method then it is showing an error: `inserNewChild is not a function`.

I am using this line, please review this and let me know where I am doing wrong.

`mygrid.insertNewChild("a0J9000000TTdLtEAL","a0J9000000TTdKz","CLASS.000010",0,0,0,0,"");`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the insertNewChild() is the method of the dhtmlxTree, and won't work in dhtmlxTreegrid.
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxtree_insertnewchild.html

You may use the addRow() method:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__link__dhtmlxtreegrid_addrow.html

Also please try to use the onOpenEnd event instead of onOpenStart:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxtreegrid_onopenend_event.html

Comment: HI Pual,   Thanks for the answer but can we add row according to parent means for example we have A as a parent then i want to fetch its child  dynamically so how we will identified record is related to which Parent.  there is any method like addRow(nodeId,ParentId,[Data]) like this. Thanks